# Concurrency with a custom DomainService

Tags: silverlight, concurrency, poco, domainservices

I have created a class that inherits for DomainService and have a Silverlight app that uses System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client to get a DomainContext. I have also created POCO DataContracts that are used in the DomainServices's Query, Update, Insert, and Delete methods.  I also have a ViewModel that executes all the LoadOperations. And now I'm at the part of my app where I want to add new Entities to the generated EntitySets but am unsure about what's going to happen when one user creates new and sets the Key value; all while another user creates a similar entity with the same Key value.

I have seen in the documentation that an ObjectContext is used, but in my situation I was not able to use the EntityFramework model generator. So I had to create my datacontracts by hand.

So I guess my question is, is there any way I can force other silverlight apps to update on database change?

Comment: EDIT: Easier question...  As I said above, I have a custom DomainService that just inherits from DomainService. Is there any way to "Refresh" the DomainContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a Save operation to your DomainContext, depending on the load behavior, it will automatically refresh.

```
TicketContext.Load(TicketContext.GetTicketByIdQuery(ticketId),
                                      LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent,
                                      x =>
                                        {
                                          Ticket = x.Entities.First();
                                          Ticket.Load();
                                          ((IChangeTracking) TicketContext.EntityContainer).AcceptChanges();
                                        }, null);
```

Here I've set the LoadBehavior to RefreshCurrent. When you make a save, RIA will send the entity back across the wire to the client and merge the changes with the entity already cached on your client side context. I don't know if that quite answers your question or not however.

Comment: In normal circumstances it would, but I was not able to use the Entity Data Model Generator. So I did not have an ObjectContext to use with LinqToEntity, and therefor found myself having to create alot of the missing functionality. But since that answer seems to answer the question I'll mark it.  Thanks for the help Chris.

Comment: @jhorton I am not using an ObjectContext here :-) Thi is not an EF thing. This is simply how RIA works, independent of the Entity Framework. Whether you're using ADO.NET and POCO's on the server side or EF, it doesn't matter. The behavior is the same - RIA will expect to send the changes back to the client and merge them (if you've set RefreshCurrent). As you found out, if you aren't using EF you have to do a lot of work yourself :-) I've done a couple projects now with POCO and ADO.NET on the server side. It's not too bad once you figure out what RIA expects to do with the data.